# Pattern matching using string interpolation

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, string-interpolation

In the following example using Scala 2.13.3 the 1st pattern matches, but the 2nd does not.

The 3rd pattern again matches, while the 4th does not (note that `separator` in the 4th match expression is enclosed in backticks, thus referencing the value defined before).

```scala
  trait A
  case object A extends A {
    def unapply(a: String): Option[A] = if (a == "my_a") Some(A) else None
  }
  trait B
  case object B extends B {
    def unapply(b: String): Option[B] = if (b == "myB") Some(B) else None
  }

  val match1 = "myB_my_a" match {
    case s"${B(b)}_${A(a)}" => Some((a,b))
    case _ => None
  } // Some((A,B))

  val match2 = "my_a_myB" match {
    case s"${A(a)}_${B(b)}" => Some((a,b))
    case _ => None
  } // None

  val match3 = "my_a__myB" match {
    case s"${A(a)}__${B(b)}" => Some((a,b))
    case _ => None
  } // Some((A,B))

  val separator = "__"
  val match4 = s"my_a${separator}myB" match {
    case s"${A(a)}${`separator`}${B(b)}" => Some((a,b))
    case _ => None
  } // None
```

Why do only the 1st and the 3rd pattern match?

Is there a good **matching** alternative to the 2nd pattern that a) is using the `unapply` methods of `A` and `B` and where b) we don't know what strings these methods are accepting?

**Edit 1**: Added case object `B` and another matching example.

**Edit 2**: Another example to illustrate jwvh's answer:

```scala
  val (a, b) = ("my_a", "myB")
  val match5 = s"${a}_${b}" match {
    case s"${`a`}_${`b`}" => Some((a, b)) // does not match
    case s"${x}_${y}" => Some((x, y)) // matches: Some(("my", "a_myB"))
  }
```

**Edit 3**: To illustrate how, unlike case class construction and extraction with `apply` and `unapply`, the construction and extraction of strings using similar string interpolation are not (and cannot be) inverse functions:

```scala
  case class AB(a: String, b: String)
  val id = (AB.apply _ tupled) andThen AB.unapply andThen (_.get)
  val compare = id(("my_a", "myB")) == ("my_a", "myB") // true

  val construct: (String, String) => String = (a,b) => s"${a}_${b}"
  val extract: String => (String, String) = { case s"${a}_${b}" => (a,b) }
  val id2 = (construct tupled) andThen extract
  val compare2 = id2(("my_a","myB")) == ("my_a","myB") // false
```

Comment: The first match is failing because there are three `_` and there is no way to specify which should match the `_` in the pattern. It is either matching `my` and `a_my_a` or `my_a_my` and `a`, none of which fit the pattern for `A.unapply`.

Comment: I added another case object and a matching example (which is now the 1st). In the 2nd case it seems like the first underscore in the string is consumed by the pattern not by `A.unapply`.

Comment: The key point is that the `unapply` on the string interpolation happens first, then the `unapply` on `A` or `B` with the resulting strings. Try `s"${a}_${b}"` to see how the string interpolation match is splitting the string.

Comment: As you suggested `"my_a_myB" match { case s"${a}_${b}" => Some((a,b)) }` results in `Some(("my","a_myB"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your own test (mentioned in the comments) demonstrates, the interpolator recognizes that the match pattern `"${A(a)}_${B(b)}"` is made up of 2 parts separated by an underscore `_`. So a best-guess effort is made to split the target string accordingly.

The 1st part, `"my"`, is sent to the `A.unapply()` where it fails. The 2nd part, `"a_myB"`, is not even attempted.

Something similar happens in `match4`. The pattern `"${A(a)}${'separator'}${B(b)}"` has 3 dollar signs and thus 3 parts. But, without any explicit characters to anchor the pattern, the target string is split into these 3 parts.

1. `""`
2. `""`
3. `"my_a__myB"`

Again, the 1st part fails the `unapply()` and the other parts are never attempted.

---

While your **Edit 3** code is technically correct, I don't find it terribly convincing. You've simply demonstrated that `(String,String)`=>`AB(String,String)`=>`(String,String)` is (or can be) a lossless data transition. The same cannot be said of `(String,String)`=>`String` which introduces some ambiguity, i.e. the loss of information sufficient to guarantee restoration of the original data. That loss is inherent in the transformation itself, not the tools (interpolation) used to achieve it.

The fact that `case class` and `String` interpolation both use `apply()`/`unapply()` under the hood strikes me as inconsequential.

Comment: So, unlike case class construction and extraction using `apply` and `unapply`, string construction and extraction using similar string interpolations are not inverse operations?

Comment: Not seeing the inherent information loss and potential ambiguity when constructing and extracting strings using string interpolation is what caused my confusion in the first place. Now it seems rather obvious. Thank you.